# Caching intermediate states of a series of computations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, composition

So, here's the concrete idea: I'm writing a Scrabble game AI, and in the process of calculating all the possible moves on the board, I have to calculate a bunch of intermediate values per board square. I'd like to cache these intermediate values in a way that's composable.

So, more abstractly:

Without caching, I have `f :: w a -> w b`, `g :: w b -> w c`, where `w` can be any functor, but in my case is the Scrabble board datatype. After adding caching, I have `f' :: m (w a) -> m (w b)`, and `g' :: m' (w b) -> m' (w c)`, where `m` and `m'` are <strike>monads</strike> datatypes* containing the cached state. But now I cannot compose `f'` and `g'`.

I'm not super familiar with monad transformers, but it sounds like if I used it here, I would need to repeatedly `lift` my monadic functions depending on how deep I was in the chain of cached-function compositions. E.g. if I had `f' . g' . h'`, my implementation of `h'` would require something like `lift . lift . lift get`. Am I off-base here? In principle, `f'`, `g'`, and `h'` are unrelated, and do not need to know about each other's cached state. Is there a better way to do things that reflects this independence?

* I don't think they have to be monads, because I'm not looking to have other functions modify `m` and `m'`. They're 'private' to `f'` and `g'` only.

Comment: it is hard to tell without seeing the code, but it looks like a case for Kleisli `(>=>)` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) ... anyway have you tried to "abuse" Haskells lazyness for the caching?

Comment: and of course you should be able to write your own composition for your *cached* `m` type

Comment: But Kleisi composition only deals with one monad, whereas I have multiple different types of cached state...

Yeah, I'm aware of how laziness can be used for caching, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in my case.

I'll see if I can come up with a small code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In general `m (w a) -> m (w b)` and `m' (w b) -> m' (w c)` don't compose.

If `m` is a `Functor` (or other covariant functor) and `m'` is "pointed" (i.e. it has a return/pure function), then you can compose to get `m (w a) -> m (m' (w c))`.

Further if `m` and `m'` and both be lifted to a common monad (i.e. functions `m a -> t a` and `m' a -> t a` exist for some monad t), then you can use those lifts and a join to produce a composition of type `m (w a) -> t (w c)`.

Independence and composition are competing goals--both good--but, to compose two things they have to have "matching shapes" which doesn't let them vary independently.